# Will disconnect from debugging mode when reaching break point

Tags: android-studio, breakpoints, oncreate, android-10.0, usb-debugging

I created a simple app and start in Android Studio version 3.6.2. I have N Android 10 real device and when I create a break point in `onCreate()`, Android Studio jumps to the break point successfully, but after 5 seconds it will disconnect from debugging mode automatically without any error or log. I searched a lot about it but I can't find out why it will disconnect automatically. Has any one had this problem in real Android and how can I solve it?

This is my code

```
Button btntest;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btntest=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btntest);

    }
```